# Фон увеличивает потребление оперативной памяти приложением на 100МБ

Tags: java, android, изображения, оптимизация, память

Пытаюсь поставить фотографию на задний план для украшения и дизайна (1080x1920 9:16), но она съедает 100мб память заставляя приложение тормозить. Как при этом мне оставить фотографию и ее качество и сохранить ценную ОЗУ?

И какое оптимальное потребление памяти android приложению 30? 20?

**Делаю через стили:**

```
  <style name="RegisterTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg</item>
</style>
```

**И манифест:**

```
 <activity android:name=".ui.activities.AuthActivity"
        android:theme="@style/RegisterTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Фото сколько весит?

Comment: проблема не в самой картинке, а её отрисовке. Расскажите зачем такой большой формат. Я на телевизоре 55 дюймов смотрю такое разрешение, а вы его на смартфон, как фон кидаете.

Comment: @post_zeew 250 Кбайт

Comment: 100мб памяти - что-то слишком жирно даже для такого разрешения. В какую папку Вы её положили?

Comment: @woesss drawable

Comment: оптимального потребления памяти для приложений нет. ваше приложение на разных телефонах может занимать разное кол-во памяти. проверено лично. ради примера приложение с гугл картами на мейзу м3с 60мб, на нексусе 6 200мб. просто старайтесь с умом писать :)

Comment: тормозит оно скорее всего из-за отрисовки как сказано выше. анроид работает так: как только на экране происходит действие (касание или анимация) весь экран начинает перерисовываться. вместе с вашей картинкой. андроид не успевает вкладываться в 60 фпс из-за картинки и начинаются фризы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного теории. Вес файла картинки не имеет значения в данном случае, так как для отображения она переводится в битмап, размер которого зависит только от разрешения и режима кодирования. `ARGB_8888` - 4 байта на пиксель, `RGB_565` - 2 байта на пиксель (без прозрачности) [и т. д.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html). При отображении Android кодирует ресурсы в формате `ARGB_8888` и изменить это нельзя (если только вручную в коде доставать каждую картинку и менять конфиг).

Ваша проблема, что вы кладёте картинку в общую папку `drawable`. Android при вытаскивании ресурсов из этой папки изменяет их размер в соответствии с текущим разрешение экрана, и вашу картинку 1080x1920, вероятно, делает ещё больше. Чтобы этого избежать, нужно помещать такие ресурсы в папку `drawable-nodpi`. Ресурсы из этой папки берутся "как есть".

Правильный же путь, это нарезать вашу картинку и разложить её по разным папкам:

- `drawable-xxhdpi` - 1920x1080 (300%)
- `drawable-xhdpi` - 1280x720 (200%)
- `drawable-hdpi` - 960x540 (150%)
- `drawable-mdpi` - 640x360 (100%)

Тогда, в зависимости от разрешения экрана, будет использоваться картинка соответствующего размера.

[Описание android.graphics.Bitmap.Config](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html)